# Vue - conditionally pass down props

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to know if there is a good way to conditionally pass down one or more props to a child component.

If there is sometimes an `id` set, then I want to pass it down. I can't set `id` to null because a prop must have a value. I have solved it before by using a "`v-if`" like this:

```
<survey-wrapper v-if="id" :inputJson="inputJson" :id="id"></survey-wrapper>

<survey-wrapper v-else :inputJson="inputJson"></survey-wrapper>     // <--  no id
```

But it's a workaround which looks bad and it becomes a lot of code if the component has many props. And what if you have two props that may be set or not?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this line `I can't set id to null because a prop must have a value`? You can always set this `id` prop to an empty string or `undefined` and do the validation on the component-level.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `v-bind` and pass it and object containing all your props. and conditionally add your `id` prop like this.

```
<survey-wrapper v-bind="{ inputJson, ...(id ? { id } : {}) }"></survey-wrapper>
```

Comment: Due to how spread works, a ternary can be simplified to `v-bind="{ inputJson, ...id && { id } }"`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using `v-bind` and dynamically creating the list of props with a method.

Here is an example:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Component v-bind="propsToPass()"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Component
  },
  data() {
    return {
      passId: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    propsToPass() {
      const result = {};

      if (this.passId) {
        result.id = 1;
      }

      return result
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In the above example, the prop `id` will only be passed if `passId` is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do so is by using v-bind with a logical operator && :

```
<survey-wrapper :inputJson="inputJson" v-bind="id && {id}" />
```

note that it will only pass the prop if (id) is available in such case id should not be required as a prop by the component.

Thanks